# Mule Esb - web service data exchange

Tags: mule, esb, rest-client

I want to pass a variable from my service code( Using Rest Client implementation) to the mule for dynamic query creation .. Please suggest ways to :
1. Where should I be setting in the variable ( header / somewhere else)
2. How do we receive the variable in the mule flow .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable as query parameters, path parameters and header also. Please use following to get variable

For query params  :- `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]`

For Header values :- `#[message.inboundProperties.name]`

For path parameter:- `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path']` operate on path for retrieval of the value else go for APIkit which provides path params as flow variables.

Hope this helps.